# Can a linear transformation have exactly one invariant line?

Tags: linear-transformations

Is it possible for a linear transformation to have exactly one invariant line? My instinct is that it is not, but I'm not sure how to go about proving it. I'm interested in the two- or- three-dimensional cases, although it would be interesting if this is something that changes at high dimensions.

Comment: $f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=(x_1+x_2,x_2+x_3,...,x_{n-1}+x_n,x_n)$ has only $(x,0,0,...,0)$.

Comment: ... or consider a rotation in 3-dimensional space.

Comment: Are you asking about nonsingular transformations? Otherwise, any transformation that has the line as its entire image, such as a projection onto the line, is an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this would correspond to a matrix with only one eigenvector.
Example: $f(x)=Ax$ with
$A=\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1\\
0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}$
or
$A=\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}$. The direction of the invariant line passing through the origin is $v=(1,0)^T$ and $v=(1,0,0)^T$, resp (that's the eigenvectors).

Comment: Or only one real eigenvalue - if the base field is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr True that!